# bootstrap data-toggle dropdown activated by radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to open a bootstrap dropdown by clicking on a radio button but as simple as that may sound, it is giving me a hell of a day.

According to Bootstrap, you can open the dropdown by use of hyperlink or button with `data-toggle="dropdown"` in it. You can also use `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` but the trigger must still have `data-toggle="dropdown"` for it to work.

The problem is, radio buttons do not allow `data-toggle="dropdown"` and if I wrap the radio option inside its own hyperlink tag and add the toggle to it, then the dropdown works, but not the radio button itself and I need both to work simultaneously. The radio button will perform an action meanwhile displaying a dropdown to allow for a secondary action.

I dumbed down the code to give a simpler example and replicate my problem. You can see in the CODEPEN that the dropdown works but the radio button does not show "Hello Offender". If you remove the `<a>...</a>` You will see the radio button work but not the dropdown. How can I get both to work?

Here is my code

```
        <div class="form-group widget-header-radio-group">
            <div class="radio-group inline-radio">
                <input id="individualForm" class="radio-custom " name="radio-group" type="radio" checked>
                <label for="individualForm" class="radio-custom-label">Individual</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio-group inline-radio">
                <input id="businessForm" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio">
                <label for="businessForm" class="radio-custom-label">Business</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio-group inline-radio">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                    <input id="offenderForm" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio">
                    <label for="offenderForm" class="radio-custom-label">Offender</label>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdownMenu">
                        <li id="stateOff"><a href="#">State</a></li>
                        <li id="federalOff"><a href="#">Federal</a></li>
                        <li id="countyOff"><a href="#">County</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="indDemo" class=""> Hello Individual</div>  
        <div id="busDemo" class=""> Hello Business</div>    
        <div id="offDemo" class=""> Hello Offender</div>    

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#busDemo').hide();
    $('#offDemo').hide();

    $('#individualForm').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#indDemo').show();
            $('#busDemo').hide();
            $('#offDemo').hide();
        }
    });

    $('#businessForm').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#busDemo').show();
            $('#indDemo').hide();
            $('#offDemo').hide();
        }
    });


    $('#offenderForm').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#offDemo').show();
            $('#indDemo').hide();
            $('#busDemo').hide();
        }
    });


});
```

See the CODEPEN [**here**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/QEokVO)

Thanks!

Comment: it might be a solution to add an change or click handler to the radio that calls the $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown() function

Comment: tried that. No cigar. There is a dependency of data-toggle dropdown that is not allowed inside a radio input type

Comment: what if you wrapped the radio in a div and add the data-toggle to that container?

Comment: data-toggle works with hyperlinks and/or buttons - per Bootstrap docs.

Answer (score 3):

Take out the radio button from inside the anchor, since the anchor is enveloping the radio button so the radio button change event is not being triggered. Modify the radio button change handler like this:

```
$('#offenderForm').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#offDemo').show();
            $('#indDemo').hide();
            $('#busDemo').hide();
            $(this).siblings('a.dropdown-toggle').click();
        }
    });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXAQXX

EDIT: Add this to your javascript code:

```
$('a.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
       $(this).siblings('input').click();
   });
```

That way when you click on the anchor, a click event on the radio button will be triggered. Likewise, when you click on the radio button, a click event on the anchor will be triggered

Comment: Your answer seemed to work with some CSS work I had to do but I have the same problem with your suggestion as @gaetanoM above. It doesn't open when I click on both the radio button or the radio label. Yours opens on the radio label which is the one with the hyperlink. the radio is still not working. +1 but not quite the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If the input field is inside the anchor the input field will never receive the change event. But you may delegate the event to the parent div and test if the anchor you are clicking contains the input element you are looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#busDemo').hide();
  $('#offDemo').hide();

  $('#individualForm').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#indDemo').show();
      $('#busDemo').hide();
      $('#offDemo').hide();
    }
  });

  $('#businessForm').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#busDemo').show();
      $('#indDemo').hide();
      $('#offDemo').hide();
    }
  });


  
  // delegate the event differently
  $('div.radio-group.inline-radio').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    var offenderForm = document.getElementById('offenderForm');
    if (this.contains(offenderForm)) {
      offenderForm.checked = !offenderForm.checked;
      if (offenderForm.checked) {
        $('#offDemo').show();
        $('#indDemo').hide();
        $('#busDemo').hide();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu{
  left: 200px;
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- unchanged HTML  -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group widget-header-radio-group">
                <div class="radio-group inline-radio">
                    <input id="individualForm" class="radio-custom " name="radio-group" type="radio" checked>
                    <label for="individualForm" class="radio-custom-label">Individual</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio-group inline-radio">
                    <input id="businessForm" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio">
                    <label for="businessForm" class="radio-custom-label">Business</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio-group inline-radio">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                        <input id="offenderForm" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio">
                        <label for="offenderForm" class="radio-custom-label">Offender</label>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdownMenu">
                            <li id="stateOff"><a href="#">State</a></li>
                            <li id="federalOff"><a href="#">Federal</a></li>
                            <li id="countyOff"><a href="#">County</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div calss="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="indDemo" class=""> Hello Individual</div>
            <div id="busDemo" class=""> Hello Business</div>
            <div id="offDemo" class=""> Hello Offender</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the only problem I saw with this is that I have to actually click on the word which is the hyperlink and it works but clicking the actual radio doesn't work :( It would be great if it did work on both for better user experience/ +1 anyway. It is a good solution, just a hair short from an answer

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```js
function hideAllbut(id) {
    $('#indDemo').hide();
    $('#busDemo').hide();
    $('#offDemo').hide();
    $('.dropdown-menu').hide()
    if (id) $('#' + id).show();
}
$('#individualForm').change(function() {
    hideAllbut('indDemo');
});

$('#businessForm').change(function() {
    hideAllbut('busDemo');
});

$('#offenderForm').click(function() {
    hideAllbut('offDemo');
    $('.dropdown-menu').dropdown().show();
});
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function() {
    $('#offDemoSub').html(this.innerHTML);
    $('.dropdown-menu').dropdown().hide();
});
hideAllbut('indDemo');
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
    left: 150px !important;
    top: 60px !important;
}
#offDemoSub { padding-left: 20px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group widget-header-radio-group">
                <div class="radio-group inline-radio">
                    <input id="individualForm" class="radio-custom " name="radio-group" type="radio" checked>
                    <label for="individualForm" class="radio-custom-label">Individual</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio-group inline-radio">
                    <input id="businessForm" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio">
                    <label for="businessForm" class="radio-custom-label">Business</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio-group inline-radio">

                    <input id="offenderForm" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio">
                    <label for="offenderForm" class="radio-custom-label">Offender</label>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdownMenu">
                        <li id="stateOff"><a href="#">State</a></li>
                        <li id="federalOff"><a href="#">Federal</a></li>
                        <li id="countyOff"><a href="#">County</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div calss="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="indDemo" class=""> Hello Individual</div>
            <div id="busDemo" class=""> Hello Business</div>
            <div id="offDemo" class=""> Hello Offender
                <div id="offDemoSub" class=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was my scapegoat if I didn't get it to work. The problem why I didn't want to go with this originally is because you can't make it go away once you open it because it is triggered to open and close only with the radio button. Having it close on mouseleave would probably be a good fix but I find it more troublesome to have to find a fix for my fix. Thanks anyway JAG